# How can I transmit a signal from my computer?

Tags: signals, device

Is there a device which allows me to transmit signals from my computer?

For example, I want my computer to transmit the signal for my car to open.

If not a device, is there another way to do it? Maybe make my computer press the remote somehow? Maybe make my computer close my remote circuit so the signal is sent?

Comment: Cmon, there are hundreds of ways to do it. Several protocols (WiFi, RF, Bluetooth, IR, etc), hundreds of devices. Please specify what do you need exactly. What have you been thinking about, whats doubts have, etc.

Comment: Well I need an IR transmitter, which can transmit to about 30 ft. (10 meters). Much like a car's remote control. I also need it to "learn" the exact frequency to transmit from my existing remote. Does this help?

Comment: IR transmitter would need line of sight, most garage door openers work off of RF (Radio Frequency) which is omni-directional and can travel through some surfaces. Like I was suggesting in my answer, if you search for an RF transmitter peripheral you could connect it through USB and then program it to transmit the code for your garage door to open. I don't think you're going to find a quick and easy solution, this will take some work on your part to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

You would need an RF transmitter peripheral for your PC and software to control it.

Answer (score 0):

You could program an arduino to move a robot arm down enough to press a remote, that's the only thing I could think of. You would need to learn some C

Comment: +1 better you add some missile launcher to hit the button.. :D